# How to synchronize taxonomies in ektron

Tags: synchronization, publish, taxonomy, ektron

I have changed something in taxonomies (target and title of one link) and now I am able to see the changes in auth environment.

How to see the changes on production env? Should I synchronise or publish something?

I am absolutely new to ektron so I feel a bit lost and the documentation is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To publish anything on the other servers (CD,test, anything) you have to trigger the eSync synchronisation.

Settings -> Configuration -> Synchronisation -> Profiles and choose the profile you want to synchronise (1st icon 'Sync' from the 'Actions' on the very right).

This synchronization has to be already setup previously. For any other information related to eSync check :
https://webhelp.episerver.com/Ektron/documentation/documentation/wwwroot/cms400/v85/webhelp/eSync/Using%20eSync/Sync_using_intro.htm